# How to add tx:annotation-driven to grails

Tags: spring, grails

I'm trying to enable aspectJ in a grails 2.4.3 project. Sources on internet usually explain for spring.

They suggest adding

`<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>`

How can we add this to a grails project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of `<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>` will be something like this in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
xmlns tx:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
tx.'annotation-driven'(mode:'aspectj')
```

Comment: Do you have a typo in the second line or is `apectj` ?

Comment: The former.  I will fix it.  Apologies.

Comment: So does it import tx namespace as aspectj?

Comment: No.  I imported the `aspectj` namespace initially but have since updated the example.

Comment: You can import any namespace using the same technique.

Comment: Haven't tried it but looks legit. Accepted, thanks!